# Unable to upload screenshot image to Google Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

In Google Cloud Platform I have enabled the **Apps Marketplace SDK** to publish a sheets-on to Marketplace.

In **APIs & Services > Apps Marketplace SDK > Publish** I am unable to upload a screenshot.  I keep getting **Not saved**.

see here:

[image]

I am using the correct size screenshot and have tried many different sizes and image types.  ex. 640x400, 1280x800 all the recommended sizes.  I have used png and jpg.

I can't click the publish button until a screenshot is uploaded.  This is weird because I was able to upload an image for application banner without issue (as shown in the image above).

Any ideas why I am getting this **Not saved** message?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue right now. Have you had any answer from G Suite Marketplace team?

Comment: I haven't contacted them, their support site directed me here.  Do they have a support email?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there is a 'Send feedback' button on the top right of the developer console.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and logged it here on the Marketplace SDK issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118943889. If anyone else is experiencing the same problem please add a star to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload your screenshots into the [Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).
Look at this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/faq#how_can_i_update_my_marketplace_listing).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the warning at the top. The Publish tab should not be used yet for add-ons created in Apps Script (Docs, Sheets, Slides and Forms).
Those details have to be filled in Chrome Web Store and after about 48hs the publication should be available in G Suite Marketplace.

The G Suite Marketplace team is working on simplifying the publishing process and in the future it won't be required to publish in Chrome Web Store.

Comment: the problem is, the fields in the 'Publish' tab are actually being shown to users (specifically the "Post install tip" and various URLs) when they install the app. There's currently no way to change any of those fields since the form won't submit, and there's no analogous field in the Chrome web store page.

Comment: Add-ons other than Gmail the "Post install tip" and other fields have to be changed in the Chrome Web Store Dashboard as Kemo said. We are in the process of migrating G Suite Add-ons from CWS to GSM, after that the publish tab will be used for all add-ons.

Comment: there's no "Post install tip" field that I can find in the Chrome Web Store Dashboard. The G Suite Marketplace dashboard won't even let me unpublish and re-publish to change the tip. Luckily, I didn't write something silly in that field.

Comment: The "Post install tip" can be entered when you publish the add-on from Apps Script in the Publish -> Publish as Sheets add-on.. dialog.